# Error in reloading taglib classes in grails 2.5.2

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.5.2 and working on a taglib. When  I execute `grails run-app` everything runs fine, but whenever I make a change in my taglib and save the file I get the following error

```
Error |
2016-02-26 16:29:30,628 [Thread-9] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [groovyPages:2.5.2] could not reload changes to file [D:\...\BootstrapTagLib.groovy]: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
    [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
Message: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
    [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
    Line | Method
->> 3241 | chooseMostSpecificParams     in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   3194 | chooseMethodInternal         in     ''
|   3137 | chooseMethod . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   1328 | getMethodWithCachingInternal in     ''
|   3405 | createPogoCallSite . . . . . in     ''
|   1314 | createPogoCallSite           in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|    150 | createPogoSite . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray
|    164 | createCallSite               in     ''
|     48 | defaultCall . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    113 | call                         in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
|    125 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    342 | doCall                       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.GroovyPagesGrailsPlugin$_closure5
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     57 | invoke                       in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    606 | invoke                       in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1426 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . .  in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     93 | invoke                       in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
|    325 | doMethodInvoke . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
|   1210 | invokeMethod                 in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|   1123 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|   1019 | invokeMethod                 in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|    426 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.Closure
|    767 | invokeOnChangeListener       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin
|    716 | notifyOfEvent . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    731 | notifyOfEvent                in     ''
|    408 | informOfClassChange . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager
|    366 | informOfFileChange           in     ''
|    226 | informPluginManager . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher
|     48 | access$400                   in     ''
|    152 | onNew . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher$1
|     76 | fireOnNew                    in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.AbstractDirectoryWatcher
|    104 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher
|    154 | run                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.DirectoryWatcher
^    161 | run . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.compiler.GrailsProjectWatcher
```

I investigated a bit and found the following [JIRA](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10735) which says that this error was fixed since grails 2.3.3. I´ll be working extensively with taglibs, and having to restart the app every time I make a change is very time consuming.

Is there an override I could do in in resources.groovy? Is this error present in grails 2.5.3 or 2.5.1?

Good day and thanks.

Comment: It seems that upgrading to version 2.5.3 or 2.5.4 does not solve the problem.